# why multiprocessing and thrrreading in python both giving error nonetype object has no attribute terminate

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
global thread1,thread2
def main_thread():
    print('here')
    global thread1,thread2
    k=0
    while True:
        k+=1
        if k==10:
            terminate_it()
            
        print(f'hello world {k}')
def terminate_it():
    global thread1,thread2
    thread1.terminate()
    thread2.terminate()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
thread2=threading.Thread(target=main_thread).start()
thread1=multiprocessing.Process(target=main_thread).start()
thread1.terminate()
```

If you run this code, you will be able to reproduce that error I just want to run a program and terminate it whenever I want it to.

I am expecting to terminate the process example:

I have a function named `func1`

Now I started to run it `Process/threading.Thread(target=func1)`

Now I want to terminate it but I can't.

Comment: you cannot terminate a thread, so there is no answer to this question ...

Comment: `.start()` doesn't return anything (it returns `None`) hence the error.

Comment: All 3 `global thread1,thread2` statements in your code are totally unnecessary. You need, for example, a `global x` statement only *within* a function *and* when there is an *assignment* to a variable named `x` and you want that to refer to a variable at module (global) scope. Without such a statement, your assignment to `x` would create a variable that is local to the current function. You don't have a single case that meet these two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You had set

```
thread2=threading.Thread(target=main_thread).start()
thread1=multiprocessing.Process(target=main_thread).start()
```

but it has to be

```
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=main_thread)
thread1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_thread)
thread2.start()
thread1.start()
```

and the process should be run inside

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**Full Code**

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time


def main_thread():
    print('here')
    k = 0
    while True:
        k += 1
        if k == 10:
            break

        print(f'hello world {k}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=main_thread)
    thread1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_thread)
    thread2.start()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.join()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    thread1.terminate()
```

**Output**

```
here
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 4
hello world 5
hello world 6
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 9
here
hello world 1
hello world 2
hello world 3
hello world 4
hello world 5
hello world 6
hello world 7
hello world 8
hello world 9
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)